# Scanning a range type using pgx

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I have column of the type int4range and would like to scan it using pgx. I am defining the type as pgtype.Int4range but I am seeing the error

```
cannot assign &{{18 2} {86 2} i e 2} to **int64
```

All I am doing is

```
for rows.Next() {
....
err = rows.Scan(
... 
&healthRange)
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scan` reads the values from the current row into dest values **positionally**. It's most likely that the parameters passed to `Scan` does not match the columns in the row.

Here is a reproducer of the issue:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/pgtype"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := pgx.Connect(pgx.ConnConfig{
        Host:     "localhost",
        Port:     5432,
        User:     "username",
        Password: "password",
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    var (
        healthRange pgtype.Int4range
        anotherVar  *int64
    )
    row := conn.QueryRow(`select '[18,86)'::int4range, 2`)
    err = row.Scan(&anotherVar, &healthRange)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", healthRange)
}
```

The error message is:

```
panic: can't scan into dest[0]: cannot assign &{{18 2} {86 2} i e 2} to **int64
```

Apply this change to fix the issue:

```
- row.Scan(&anotherVar, &healthRange)
+ row.Scan(&healthRange, &anotherVar)
```

BTW, `pgtype.Int4range` is in `github.com/jackc/pgx@v3`, which was first published in 2017. Consider upgrading to the latest version, `github.com/jackc/pgx/v5`.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing `::int4range` in the Select statement

Comment: `::int4range` is not needed if the column has the type `int4range` in a real table.

Comment: My table had int4range as the type, I defined it as 
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD COLUMN healthrange int4range DEFAULT '[18,86]'::int4range NOT NULL. 
Do you think it could be because of the default?

Comment: The definition is correct. `&{{18 2} {86 2} i e 2}` in the error message means that the range value has been parsed correctly. Like I said in the answer, it's most likely that the reason is a mismatch between the columns and the parameters passed to `Scan`.